# Win7 and Ubuntu installed on hard drive used simultaneously - virtualization

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, multi-boot, vmware-player

I'd like to run Linux(Ubuntu) which is installed on hard disk (Ext4) inside Windows7. Use two OSes, installed on hard disk simultaneously.

I've found how to do this in other way around (VirtualBox) - Linux as Host, Windows7 on physical partition as Guest. I haven't tested it yet, but I've read it's possible.

I've found something in VMWare Player - Add physical partition/disk, but it seems this solution can't boot VM from those partitions, just mount them to existing VM.

I'd like to have a way to run Windows7 and Ubuntu natively or Ubuntu as Host & Win7as Guest or Win7 as Host & Ubuntu as Guest.

I have to switch between OSes multiple times and it will really saves my time.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid using virtual disk files?

Comment: Because I'd like to boot systems natively and virtually inside each other. It's strictly connected to how I work on my pc. Often I'm working on Linux, but need something from my Windows or I have to write something in C# for someone. I don't want to stop current work, reboot, switch to Windows for 15 min and go back to linux. And in the other way around. I want to natively run windows, install software, bla bla bla and later use it on linux. There are days when I'm using only windows and days when I'm using only linux. I don't want waste resources for virtualization if there is a better way.

Comment: The Virtualbox documentation says it can do this both ways round.  Of course you'll need to run it as admin.  Failing that, I suggest you investigate server virtualization products, as it makes more sense in that context (since the VM is expected to be running in system context instead of standard user context).  I'm not sure how you would go about building a Windows instance that can boot from either virtual or physical hardware, but apparently people have been able to do this, presumably using separate hardware profiles.

Comment: At the risk of improperly using `comments` section, care to share how you got an existing Win7 install to run under Ubuntu `virtualbox`? http://superuser.com/q/839827

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be booting into different OS's multiple times, just go for something quick and easy. [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is pretty foolproof, and I use it at home to switch into `<linux flavour of choice>` when I need to do work related things or when I feel the need to tinker.

You can do it the other way around (Virtualized-Windows running on a Linux Host) if you feel like it. It's entirely up to you.

[image: This is what my desktop looks like at the moment. Linux flavour on the left, windows on the right.]

Comment: I also think virtualbox is good choice and I'd like to use it. I wrote above about virtualized-Windows on Linux-Host. Right now I'd like to know if that other scenario is possible. virtualized-linux on Windows Host. And everything from hard disk, not virtual disk created by VBox/VmWare

Comment: Well sure, Linux on Windows works (above screenshot is proof). Also, do you mean you want to attach a real physical disk to a guest??